# Diacritics and using TAB to change focus in a WPF application hostet in Winforms ElementHost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a WPF Application hostet in a WinForms ElementHost.
When a diacritic character (e.g. "^" or "`") is entered in a Textbox, NOT followed by a literal, changing focus by pressing TAB does not work. A literal character must be typed first to make TAB work again.

In a native WPF application the diacritic gets displayed in the TextBox when pressing TAB, further presses of TAB change focus. The ElementHost seems to inhibit this behavior.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Workaround has been found by overriding OnKeyDown Method and checking e.DeadCharProcessedKey.

```
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DeadCharProcessedKey == Key.Tab)
        {
            _ChangeFocus(e);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        }
    }

    private static void _ChangeFocus(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var direction = Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift ? FocusNavigationDirection.Previous : FocusNavigationDirection.Next;
        var focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;

        if (focusedElement != null && focusedElement .MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(direction)))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```